# Showing the value of a selected option rather than the text in a html select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` with all options following this format (a,b,c,d).
E.g. '1000, Balance, 0, 4'.
The dropdown menu (which is actually in some cases a popup window with a searchable/filterable list) should show the options as shown in the above example, but when an option has been selected, the actual `select` box should only show the first value.
E.g. '1000'.
How would you go about doing this? I'm using javaScript and jQuery along with the html. Don't worry about extracting the right value to show, I basically just want to know how to set the shown value to something else than the actual value.

I have a method that returns the value I want to display (e.g. '1000'), so I would like to do something similar to

```
$("#selectID").val("1000");
```

The options are added like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.dataTable().Rows().length; i++) { 
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = this.getDataTableText(this.dataTable().Rows()[i]).replace(/\s{2,}/g, '');
        option.value = this.getDataTableText(this.dataTable().Rows()[i]).replace(/\s{2,}/g, '').split(",")[0];
        sel.options.add(option, (i)); 
    }
```

So I would just like to set the shown value to the value of the option rather than the text.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Show your code, then we will help you.

Comment: Do you mean something different than `this.getDataTableText(this.dataTable().Rows()[i]).replace(/\s{2,}/g, '');`?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to show options.value in the select box rather than options.text